# Good design patterns or open-source software for large scale user email/messaging system?

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, mongodb, scalability

Our group is tasked with designing and implementing a large user-to-user internal messaging system (similar to facebook messages). The system is expected to handle at least a billion messages.

The system will be built using php and either mysql or a nosql database, and we are open to any technologies that will be helpful.

An internal messaging system like this is probably very common, and has probably been built hundreds of times by different companies in the past, and we don't want to reinvent the wheel.

**Are there any standard design patterns for such a task that have been used in the past and held up well?**

Books or guides or just general advice would be very useful.

(If you know of any open-source (or closed-source) software that is recommended that would be helpful in designing this system, that would also be appreciated!)

Comment: Possibly better on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)? I can't decide.

Comment: i heard FB uses XMPP http://xmpp.org/

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - there's plenty of pre-made systems that scale nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This may be better suited to programmers.stackexchange.com but there is at least part of your question that can be answered here.

**Are there any standard design patterns?** Yes.

If the messages might ever become live (chats, for example), then XMPP is a great choice to make. [Wikipedia sums up its strengths well and does mention a weakness.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)  It's also nice because your users don't NEED to use your client to talk, any XMPP client will do. This is a big point in its favor (in my opinion).

Since this is tagged PHP, here are two XMPP implementations in PHP I know of:

**Lightr** http://code.google.com/p/lightr/

> Lightr is an XMPP and BOSH client written in object-oriented PHP5. It is intended to be run on-interval by an AJAX-enabled frontend and utilizes the CURL library to handle connections with a BOSH server.

**XMPPHP** http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/

> XMPPHP is the successor to Class.Jabber.PHP that I've been promising for years. Taking advantage of PHP5, I believe it to be an elegant solution with a direct approach.Some of the features include:
>   - Connect to any XMPP 1.0 server (Google Talk, LJ Talk, jabber.org, etc 
>   - Supports TLS encryption
>   - Several XML processing approaches and supported styles (process indefinitely, processUntil an event, processTime for a number of seconds), waiting on events or map them, etc.

I have not used either of them.  Someone else may be able to answer the second part of your question.

Comment: Thanks Levi! Great Answer. I hadn't thought of using XMPP. Do you know if xmpp can (easily) scale to hundreds of millions of messages, and where it would store the messages in persistence (e.g. is it stored in a mysql database)?